# How to make deleted emails on Gmail go to Trash folder?

Tags: gmail

When I used to have a Hotmail account, I am pretty certain that emails I delete moved straight to the deleted box. This was useful in case I accidentally deleted an email that was important.

However in Gmail it appears there is no "deleted" box, and only a Trash folder. However, when I delete emails they do not appear in Trash - e.g. I just deleted five emails and my trash folder is empty.

Is there a way I can either create/enable a deleted folder or make all emails I delete go to Trash, even if for just 30 days?

Comment: Did you check **All Mail** ?

Comment: Did you delete them? or did you archive them?

Comment: The normal action when deleting messages in Gmail is for them to go to Trash. After 30 days, they'll be cleared out of Trash permanently. Are you using something else to connect to Gmail?

Answer (score 1):

From [Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7015314?hl=en):

> **Check if the email was archived, deleted, or marked as spam**
>
> Emails might skip your inbox if they were accidentally archived, deleted, or marked as spam.
>
> Follow these steps to search all your emails, including those that aren't in your inbox:
>
> > 1. On your computer, open [Gmail](https://mail.google.com/).
> > 2. In the search box, click the Down arrow Down Arrow.
> > 3. Click the **All Mail** drop down, then select **Mail & Spam & Trash**.
> > 4. Enter some information that’s in the missing email. If you're not sure about exact words or details, leave the fields blank.
> > 5. At the bottom of the box, click Search Search.
>
> **Tip:** To filter your search results even more, you can also use [search operators](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190).